# Suggestion needed in nested Jquery call

Tags: jquery

I have two validation jQuery functions which I need to fire one after another. If the first validation is passed then only the second fucnction should call. In my case both of them are firing simulteniously. Here is the code

```
$("#btnValidate").live('click', function (event) {
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            procCode: '001'
        },
        url: "jsp/Process.jsp",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#tdValidYN").html(result);
            if (document.getElementById('hidValidYN').value == 'N') {
                alert("Validation Failed. Required Columns Missing");
                $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', true);
            } else {
                alert("Validation Passed");
                $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            procCode: '002'
        },
        url: "jsp/Process.jsp",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#tdValidYN").html(result);
            if (document.getElementById('hidValidYN').value == 'N') {
                alert("Validation Failed. Invalid Parameters Used");
                $('#btnCreateTable').attr('disabled', true);
            } else {
                alert("Validation Passed");
                $('#btnCreateTable').attr('disabled', false);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I tried to put the second function under the if condition of the the first function but script error is happening.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this may work:

```
$("#btnValidate").live('click', function(event) {
    $.ajax({ 


         data: {procCode: '001'},
                              url:"jsp/Process.jsp",
                              success:function(result){
                                 $("#tdValidYN").html(result);
                                 if(document.getElementById('hidValidYN').value=='N'){
                                     alert("Validation Failed. Required Columns Missing");
                                     $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', true);
                                 }else{
                                     alert("Validation Passed");
                                     $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false);

                                             $.ajax({ 
                                                  data: {procCode: '002'  },
                                                  url:"jsp/Process.jsp",
                                                  success:function(result){

                                                         $("#tdValidYN").html(result);
                                                         if(document.getElementById('hidValidYN').value=='N'){
                                                             alert("Validation Failed. Invalid Parameters Used");
                                                             $('#btnCreateTable').attr('disabled', true);
                                                         }else{
                                                             alert("Validation Passed");
                                                             $('#btnCreateTable').attr('disabled', false);
                                                         }
                                                  }
                                            });
                                 }

                              }
                        });


}
```

if thats what you tried, whats the error your getting ?

Comment: I have tried the same way before and got some script exception like object is null. But now again with this try I succeded. Thank you very much.

Comment: no probs dude, i just dealt with a heap of this in a one page checkout ajax mod for opencart so i recognised it straight away...

Comment: it sure works, but imagine you need to chain 5 calls, it would be a nightmare to pass callbacks inside callbacks. The preferred way is to use a deferred object, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you want to issue the second ajax request only if the first one is successful. Instead of doing callback spaghetti, it's better to use Deferred objects.

http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/

the code would be something like:

```
$("#btnValidate").live('click', function (event) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        data: {
            procCode: '001'
        },
        url: "jsp/Process.jsp",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#tdValidYN").html(result);
            if (document.getElementById('hidValidYN').value == 'N') {
                alert("Validation Failed. Required Columns Missing");
                $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', true);
                d.reject();
            } else {
                alert("Validation Passed");
                $('#btnSave').attr('disabled', false);
                d.resolve();
            }
        }
    });

    d.done(function(){
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                procCode: '002'
            },
            url: "jsp/Process.jsp",
            success: function (result) {
                $("#tdValidYN").html(result);
                if (document.getElementById('hidValidYN').value == 'N') {
                    alert("Validation Failed. Invalid Parameters Used");
                    $('#btnCreateTable').attr('disabled', true);
                } else {
                    alert("Validation Passed");
                    $('#btnCreateTable').attr('disabled', false);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This way, the second ajax request (the callback passed the `done` function) will only run if the first call succeeds (see that it runs `d.resolve()`). If the validation goes wrong, `d.reject()` is called and no callback would run (strictly speaking, when you call `reject` the callbacks passed to `fail` would run, but as none were added, nothing runs).

Edit: actually, `$.ajax` returns a deferred object, so we could do something like:

```
var d = $.ajax({ ... });
d.done(function(result) {
    // this runs when the ajax call succeeds, it's the success callback
});
```

But that would require a longer refactoring.

A reference to the deferred object: http://joseoncode.com/2011/09/26/a-walkthrough-jquery-deferred-and-promise/

Comment: i think this guys onto something

Answer (score 0):

insert your second jQuery `$.ajax` call inside the `success: function(){ }` parameter.. it will be executed after the first `$.ajax` call is successfully executed.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you have written will obviously won't work for the simple reason that javascript gets executed sequentially. Make the second call inside `success` callback of the first call. Or you can put the second call inside a named function and call it from inside the success callback of first function to make the code appear neater.